# ¿Es posible aparecer y desaparecer un div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, div, dropdownlist

He logrado que un div sea visible cuando elijo una opción, pero ¿hay posibilidad de eliminar el div cuando tome otra opción o que se sobrescriba?, ejemplo:

Al elegir **una opción** me muestra la lista **drop2.1**
pero al elegir **otra opción** me muestra la lista **drop2.2** y se oculte **drop2.1** o si elijo la opción vacía, se oculten las otras listas.

No sé si sea posible, soy muy nuevo en el desarrollo web, pero si pudieran orientarme me ayudaría a aprender nuevos métodos.

```js
function ToggleDiv(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"
}

function dropdown2(dos, ) {

  if (drop1 = b) {
    document.getElementById(dos).style.display = "block";
  } else if (drop1 = ah)

  {
    document.getElementById(dos).style.display = "block";
  }
  div
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name='drop1' style="width:150px;" onchange="ToggleDiv(this.value)">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="b">una opcion</option>
  <option value="ah">otra opcion</option>
</select>

<div id="b">
  <select name='drop2.1' style="width:150px;" onchange="dropdown2(this.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="in">ejemplo</option>
  </select>
  <div id="ah">
    <select name='drop2.2' style="width:150px;" onchange="dropdown2(this.value)">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="y">example</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="in">
    <select name='drop3' style="width:150px;">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="in">posiblidades</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ejemplo exacto de lo que quieres sería de la siguiente forma:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div#b, div#ah{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <select name='drop1' style="width:150px;" onchange="ToggleDiv(this.value)">
        <option value="none"></option>
        <option value="b">una opcion</option>
        <option value="ah">otra opcion</option>
    </select>

    <div id="b">
        <select name='drop2.1' style="width:150px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="in">ejemplo</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="ah">
        <select name='drop2.2' style="width:150px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="y">example</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="in">
        <select name='drop3' style="width:150px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="in">posiblidades</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ToggleDiv(id) {
            if (id == 'b') {
                document.getElementById('b').style.display = "block"
                document.getElementById('ah').style.display = "none"
            }else if(id == 'ah') {
                document.getElementById('b').style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById('ah').style.display = "block"
            }else{
                document.getElementById('b').style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById('ah').style.display = "none"
                document.getElementById('in').style.display = "none"
            }
        }

    </script>
```

En es `style` dejamos oculto de inicio los select `drop2.1` y `drop2.2` y `drop3` visible.

Como la visibilidad de los `div` únicamente depende del primer select `drop1`, no necesitas capturar ningún evento `onchange` en el resto de selects.

Con `ToggleDiv` enviamos el valor seleccionado. Dentro indicamos que `div`'s mostrar y ocultar con condiciones `if` según si el valor es `b` o `ah`
En caso de no seleccionar ningún valor, se ocultarán los 3 select: `drop2.1`, `drop2.2` y `drop3`.

Comment: Hola! sería excelente que pudieras explicar lo que hace tu código :)

Comment: Buenas! Eso está hecho ;) Espero que con la explicación añadida sea suficiente! Un saludo ^^

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio tu idea.

Answer (score 1):

Pues ya te dieron la respuesta, con la propiedad none; te recomiendo que trabajes con los Id's de esa forma puede ser cualquier elemento html

```
    <div id="div" class="display:block;">
        <p>Estoy mostrandome</p>
    </div>
    <button id="agregar" type="button" onclick="ocultarMostrar()">Mostrar</button>

    <script>
        function ocultarMostrar(){
            if(document.getElementById('div').style.display === "block"){
                document.getElementById('div').style.display = "none";
            }else{
            document.getElementById('div').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ocultar un div con el método que necesitas puedes poner `none` a la propiedad display.

```js
function showA () {

document.getElementById("a").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("b").style.display="none"
document.getElementById("c").style.display="none"

}

function showB () {

document.getElementById("a").style.display="none"
document.getElementById("b").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("c").style.display="none"

}

function showC () {

document.getElementById("a").style.display="none"
document.getElementById("b").style.display="none"
document.getElementById("c").style.display="block"

}
```

```html
<button onclick="showA()">a</button>
<button onclick="showB()">b</button>
<button onclick="showC()">c</button>
<div style="display:none" id="a">a</div>
<div style="display:none" id="b">b</div>
<div style="display:none" id="c">c</div>
```

Si intentas hacer un SPA o algo parecido, te recomiendo que trabajes con algún framework (vue, react, angular), ahorrarás tiempo y conocerás algo nuevo.

Comment: Gracias, pero ¿No es posible con listas desplegables?

Comment: Claro sólo tiene que leer el evento onChange del select `onchange="funcion(evento)"`